# Mute sound on shutdown and reboot scripts not working

Tags: sound, shutdown, reboot, automatic, mute

I have a working script that mutes my sound. The script is:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master mute
```

I want to let this script run on shutdown and reboot so that when I turn on my PC, the sound is muted. If I run this script manually before shutdown/reboot, then it works and my sound gets muted and is muted on startup.

However, I can't get it to run automatically. I have tried shutdown, reboot and startup seperately using [this guide](http://ccm.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown#to-execute-a-script-at-shutdown/%22Link%20to%20guide%22).

For shutdown I tried editing /etc/rc6.d. For reboot I tried putting my script in /etc/rc0.d. for startup I tried editing /etc/rc.local.

Does someone know the solution?

Thanks :) !

PS: The reason for this is that my thinkpad laptop make a loud popping noise from the speaker at startup and this is prevented by starting it up muted.